# get no return value when the child class extends to the parent class java inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am a beginner, I am trying to learn about the inheritance concept in java, I make a program to calculate the area of ​​a square and the volume of a cube, I make the cube class extends to the square class

**Square(Parent)**

```
public class Persegi {

double sisi;

public double getSisi() {
    return sisi;
}

public void setSisi(double sisi) {
    this.sisi = sisi;
}

public double getLuas(){
    return sisi * sisi;
}
}
```

**Cube(Child)**

```
public class Kubus extends Persegi{

Persegi psg = new Persegi();

public double getVolume(){
 return psg.getLuas() * psg.getSisi();
}
```

but when I print the value in the main class, the child class doesn't get the value from the method I created in the parent class

**Main Class**

```
public class MainProgram {
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    Persegi persegi = new Persegi();
    Kubus kubus = new Kubus();
    
    Scanner nilai = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Masukkan nilai sisi = ");
    persegi.setSisi(nilai.nextInt());
    
    System.out.println("Luas = "+persegi.getLuas());
    System.out.println("Volume = "+kubus.getVolume());
}
```

and the result is like this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsQDd.png)

Comment: You haven't called `setSisi()` on the `Kubus` instance, only on the `Persegi` instance. Therefore, `kubus.getSisi()` returns zero, and zero multiplied by anything is, unsurprisingly, zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`persegi` and `kubus` are two different objects. You haven't set any attribute of `kubus`. So the default value for double type in Java `0.0` is printed for `kubus.getVolume()`

You're using `psg` object's attributes to calculate the return value of the `getVolume()` method.

If you would have add a getter and setter for `psg` :

```
public class Kubus extends Persegi {

    Persegi psg = new Persegi();

    public double getVolume() {
        return psg.getLuas() * psg.getSisi();
    }

    public Persegi getPsg() {
        return psg;
    }

    public void setPsg(Persegi psg) {
        this.psg = psg;
    }
}
```

Then you can set attributes of the `psg` object:

```
Persegi persegi = new Persegi();
Kubus kubus = new Kubus();

Scanner nilai = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Masukkan nilai sisi = ");
persegi.setSisi(nilai.nextInt());

kubus.getPsg().setSisi(3.0); // assign 3.0 to sisi attribute of kubus object
    
System.out.println("Luas = "+persegi.getLuas());
System.out.println("Volume = "+kubus.getVolume());
```

Then you get the results:

```
Masukkan nilai sisi = 4
Luas = 16.0
Volume = 27.0
```

Explanation for `Volume = 27.0` output:

- `getLuas()` returns `3*3 = 9`
- `getSisi()=3`
- `getVolume()` returns
  `psg.getLuas() * psg.getSisi()` : `9*3=27`

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
public class Kubus extends Persegi{

    Persegi psg = new Persegi();

    public double getVolume(){
     return psg.getLuas() * psg.getSisi();
    }
}
```

use

```
public class Kubus extends Persegi{
    public double getVolume(){
     return getLuas() * getSisi();
    }
}
```

You don't need to create an instance of the parent class in your child class, your child object is already an instance.

And (as others already mentioned), you have to call `setSisi()` on the `Kubus` instance

And in your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Persegi persegi = new Persegi();
    Kubus kubus = new Kubus();

    kubus.setSisi(42); // you have to set the 'sisi' of the kubus ... 42 = magic number

    Scanner nilai = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Masukkan nilai sisi = ");
    persegi.setSisi(nilai.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Luas = " + persegi.getLuas());
    System.out.println("Volume = " + kubus.getVolume());
}
```

Comment: While this is true, it's not the reason behind the described behaviour. The code you propose will still return zero if the cube remains uninitialized (i.e. if `setSisi()` is not called on the cube instance).

Comment: i have tried not to call the `Persegi` class to the `Kubus` class. But the result is same, the volume value is still null

Comment: @bbqapps Again, you need to call `setSisi()` on the `Kubus` instance. Otherwise, `getSisi()`, which you use in your methods to get the area and volume, will return zero.